# Bash MySQL Dump AWS Lambda

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to create a lambda function that runs a bash file to mysqldump a db, gzip it, and move it to S3. I'm including a 'mysqldump' binary file in the zip because evidently the command is not available natively on the lambda server. I have a bootstrap file straight from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html) and I'm able to echo all of my environment variables from a handler in my bash file:

```
handler () {
   set -e

   TIMEE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S)

   echo "Backing up ${EXPORT_DB_NAME} to ${EXPORT_S3_PATH}/${EXPORT_DB_NAME}.sql using host: ${DB_HOST} and user: ${DB_USERNAME}"

   ./mysqldump --host ${DB_HOST} --opt -u ${DB_USERNAME} -p${DB_PASSWORD} ${EXPORT_DB_NAME} | gzip | aws s3 cp - s3://${EXPORT_S3_PATH}/${EXPORT_DB_FOLDER}/${EXPORT_DB_NAME}-$TIMEE.sql.gz
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> {
> "errorMessage": "RequestId: 22bc7a9f-6218-4872-a098-4d27918e4f1c Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 127",
> "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError"

/var/task/export.sh: line 9: aws: command not found
}

Looks like the aws command won't run -- why would the aws cli not work on the lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the aws command running inside the lambda function via 'layers' [following the steps here](https://github.com/gkrizek/bash-lambda-layer#ARN). This immediately solved my problem and everything is working now.